# Views remove link to content based on publication status

Tags: views, theming, hooks

Drupal 8. I have a list of images that link back to a content page. If the page is unpublished I want to remove the link.

So far I've set up a `hook_post_render` that checks the publication status. The only way I can think to move forward is to make make the view put out a link as a separate field, then conditionally remove the value. I don't love it and I'd rather jump in to where views is wrapping the image.

Answer (score 0):

With Views's support for Twig, you can now implement conditional hyperlinking without any hook modification to your view.

1. Add a *Content: Path* field to your view with **Exclude from display** checked.
2. Add a *Content: Publishing status* field to your view with **Exclude from display** checked, using the *True/False* **Output format**.
3. Add a *Image (field_my_image_field:target_id)* relationship to your view that targets your specific image.
4. Add a *File: URI* field to your view with the **Exclude from display** checked, using the *File URI* as the **Formatter**, and the **Display the file download URI** checked.
5. Finally, add a *Global: Custom* field with custom Twig that can check the publishing status value for displaying the link and use the excluded fields as replacement patterns.

For example:

```
{% if status == 'True' %}
<a href="{{path}}">
  <img src="{{uri}}" />
</a>
{% else %}
  <img src="{{uri}}" />
{% endif %}
```